# Can anyone help identify this old 1930s plane?

Tags: aircraft-identification, biplane

I would like to identify this plane, if anyone can help? All I can tell you is that it is from an old photo album and probably an English Airshow in the 1920's or 1930's.

[image: photograph]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is the [Boulton & Paul Overstrand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boulton_%26_Paul_Overstrand#Operational_history). A twin-engine biplane medium bomber, built for the Royal Air Force of the United Kindom starting from 1933. The last one was already retired in 1941. Apparently this was the first bomber with a closed power-assisted gun turret.

Comment: Still building in 1941?  Seems unlikely.

Comment: quiet flyer - the Overstrands were built in 1933-34 and the last was retired in 1941. They were used as trainers in their last years.

Comment: You are both right! Corrected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, bogl.